# Help with sum of series

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis

How can I find the sum of sum of series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(2n^2+3)}{(2\cdot 3^n)}$? I proved that it is convergent, but I am stuck. I tried putting $x$ instead $3$ and studied it as a power series, but it didn't help. I also operated and reduced the problem to find the sum of $n^2 x^n$, but I couln't conclude anything.

My attemp:
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(2n^2+3)x^n}{2}= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} n^2 x^n + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{3 x^n}{2}$$

The last sum is $3/2$ times the sum of the geometric series (convergent iff  $|x|<1$), $\frac{1}{1-x}$. But I don't know how to work with the first sum.

Comment: To avoid closing and down vote please show your Idea,effort and describe more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a hint : separation is the clue
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(2n^2+3)}{(2\cdot 3^n)}
\\\frac 12\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(2n^2+3)}{3^n}
\\\frac 12\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{2n^2}{3^n}+\frac 12\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{3}{3^n}
$$
the second part is the geometric progression but for the first, you can start with $f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n$ then find $f'(x)$ then multiply by $x$ then...can you take over now?

Comment: $x\cdot f'(x) = \sum_{n=1} nx^n$, with $f(x) = \frac{1}{1-x}$, which I can derive. But I need a square on $n$, and I don't have it.

Comment: You can derive again, and multiply by x.

Comment: go on with $$x\cdot f'(x) = \sum_{n=1} nx^n$$and derive ,so you have $n \times nx^{n-1}$ in the sum